# change data frame columns to rows

Tags: r, dataframe, rows, reshape

Sorry if this is obvious: I found a lot of questions similar to mine but I can't figure it out for my own data. I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
A <- c(1,6)
B <- c(2,7)
C <- c(3,8)
D <- c(4,9)
E <- c(5,0)
df <- data.frame(A,B,C,D,E)
df
  A B C D E
1 1 2 3 4 5
2 6 7 8 9 0
```

And I need this:

```
df
   X1  
A  1   
A  6
B  2  
B  7
C  3  
C  8
D  4       
D  9
E  5  
E  0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at `stack`

```
> stack(df)
   values ind
1       1   A
2       6   A
3       2   B
4       7   B
5       3   C
6       8   C
7       4   D
8       9   D
9       5   E
10      0   E
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that did it! I was trying to use `reshape` with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use melt(df) from reshape2 package. Its a powerful package to get used to if you often do these kind of operations.